# what command to use on hdinsight hive editor to connect to a particular storage

Tags: hadoop, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight

what command to use on hdinsight hive editor to connect to a particular storage?by b.lodefault the hive editor is connecting to the wrong storage what command should i give for it to use the right storage blob?How do i configure hive using the hive editor?

Thanks

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

If your cluster was configured with multiple storage accounts, you just need to use the URI format:

```
wasb[s]://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>
```

*Reference: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/*

For example, you if you want to list the contents of 'mycontainer' in 'mystorageaccount', you can run the following through the Hive Editor:

```
dfs -ls wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/;
```

If you haven't already configured the storage account with your cluster, you can set the required access key in the hive session like:

```
set fs.azure.account.key.mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net=LONG_KEY_GOES_HERE;
```

*Note: The account keys are per-Storage Account, not per-Container. If you are using multiple Containers in one Storage Account, the key only has to be set once.*